# Pass data object to component from Vue for loop

Tags: javascript, json, object, vue.js

So i have some object with posts, and i'm using v-for to iterate them in the custom component, but how to pass data from this object to this component, loop is a one thing displaying data i another...

```
<app-single-post v-for="post in posts" postData="$post"></app-single-post>
```

This is my component declaration. Do i need also some kind of special prop setup? Have the same error, again and again:

`Property or method "postData" is not defined`

Comment: You can pass data into a component via 'Props'. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props for more details. Props should also be set as kebab case eg 'post-data' on the html element.

Comment: what you mean data vie props? can you show some example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [binding syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props).

```
<app-single-post v-for="post in posts" :post="post" :key="post.id"></app-single-post>
```

Camel-cased properties need to be converted to kebab-case when they are used as attributes. Also, I added a [key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key). You should always use a `key` when you use `v-for` and it is required when you iterate over a custom component. Ideally you would want to use a `post.id` if one is available.

In your component, you should have a property defined like this:

```
export default {
    props:["post"],
    methods: {...},
    etc.
}
```

To reference the post in your component template you can use

```
 {{post.id}}
```

and inside methods it would be

```
this.post
```

Comment: ok, but how to get acces to the object in component by `{{post.id}}` i have undefined error :(

Comment: @Lukas in your component you need to define the property, `props: ["postData"]`.

Comment: @lukas you want it called `post` in the component?

Comment: Are you sure that individual objects in `posts` have a key called `id`? If not, it will throw an undefined error.

Comment: @Terry I inferred it from his comment; but you're right if it's not there it'll be undefined.

Comment: You can use the index returned from the iterable as key instead, i.e. `<app-single-post v-for="(post, idx) in posts" :post="post" :key="idx"></app-single-post>`

Comment: @Terry thats true, but I've run into bugs when the array mutates. Added or removed values, etc. Safer to have a hard id, or use the object itself.

Comment: Definitely, I will always pick a relevant ID instead of just the index. However, if none is available, index is the next best thing you have for the compulsory key attribute.